# Mocha unit testing routes return 200 ok

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, mocha.js

I am using mocha to test if some routes I have added to my server are returning 200 ok and if the response contains a string. I am doing this it the following manner:

```
var testDBRoute = function(link, routeName) {
    it('should return 200 OK for ' + routeName, function (done) {
        http.get(link, function (res) {
            assert.equal(200, res.statusCode);
            done();
        })
    });

    it('should return the correct info',
        function(done) {
            http.get(link, function (res) {
                var body = '';

                res.on('data', function(chunk) {
                    body += chunk;
                });

                res.on('end', function() {
                    var response = JSON.parse(body);
                    assert.equal('abc', response.id);   
                    done();
                });
            });

        }
    )
    };
```

I am calling this function 6 times in the same way:

```
describe('/link1', function () {
            var link = HOST + '/api/link1/';
            testDBRoute(link, 'link1');
});
```

No matter the order of the requests it always fails at the 8'th test meaning that it's making 8 http get requests and then fails with this error:

Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded
  at null. (\node_modules\mocha\lib\runnable.js:158:19)
  at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:112:15)

I must specify that I am running the test on windows.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the issue using [superTest](https://www.npmjs.org/package/supertest) to replace http like this

```
var request = require('supertest');
var app = require('../server');
// app is the express context from the server
    describe('GET /api', function () {
        it('test api', function (done) {
            request(app)
                .get('/api')
                .end (function (err, res) {
                     assert.equal(200, res.statusCode);
                     done();
                 });
        });
    });
```

So it seems like the problem is in the http module...